# Compare and find the extra rows in two datarames with only one common column but different number of rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes like this:

[image]

As you can see, df1 has more rows than df2. Only one column COMPANY is common to them.
I want to find out the rows which are extra in df1, comparing only the COMPANY column of both dataframes (no other column can be compared).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [pandas.Series.isin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and boolean indexing.

```py
df1[~(df1['COMPANY'].isin(df2['COMPANY'].unique()))]
```